# SQL Insert query from flask not working

Tags: python, sql

```
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (name TEXT)')
print("Table created successfully")
db.execute('INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)' % ('test', 'sample'))
db.close()
```

I am using Python. The table is created successfully with a column of "name", but I am unable to insert anything.

I get the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: sample
```

Why?

Comment: Just as a comment, I suggest you look into SQLAlchemy, it will make your life easier.

Comment: @mmenschig, I saw that, but I realized I might as well learn the SQL language. Beneficial for employment isn't it?

Comment: While I agree that SQL is beneficial to know, I would encourage you to transition to SQLAlchemy once you've grasped the SQL basics. I suggest you complete some SQL courses online and use SQLAlchemy for python projects going forwards.

Comment: hmmm.  you definitely don't want to use string substitutions.  That opens you to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection.  Use  `db.execute('INSERT INTO text VALUES (?)', 'sample')` instead.  (yes, I know that makes your tablename non-dynamic, but you can put it in the query string ahead of time if you need.  Bottom line:  never trust data that could come from a malicious party.  Knowing this is beneficial for employment too ;-)  Note:  I am not trying to answer your question in general, just flagging this vulnerability in your approach.

Comment: never mind, it would *also* probably fix your error, as you seem to be missing parentheses as per Laur Ivan.  That's one additional benefit of binding, it takes care of quotes and None=>Null conversions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like:

```
INSERT INTO test (name)
VALUES
  ('sample');
```

Translated into python:

```
db.execute('INSERT INTO %s (name) VALUES (\'%s\')' % ('test', 'sample'))
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around your VALUES substitution.  i.e. you are not actually executing your hardcoded query string.  `('sample')` is what you want, but you will get `(sample)`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the column name?

```
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (name TEXT)')
print("Table created successfully")
db.execute('INSERT INTO %s (name) VALUES (%s)' % ('test', 'sample')) 
db.close()
```

Comment: Error, no such column, "sample"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your changes.  If you don't call `db.commit()`, your changes (including creating the table) will be rolled back when you close the database.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
db.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s)' % ('sample'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You definitely don't want to use string substitutions. That opens you to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection. Instead, use database binding which incidentally fixes your actual error (which is that you are treating `sample` as a column name, rather than data).

Ok, might as well write it up:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory')

#you control this stuff, as the db schema isn't typically coming from user data
#so less likely to be a mess...
#i.e. build your query templates with string substitutions, but exec with binds.
tablename = 'test'
db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (name TEXT)' % (tablename))
print("Table created successfully")
qry = 'INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?)' % (tablename)

#the data is where you want to be careful
db.execute(qry, ('sample',))
print ("insert done")
db.close()
```

which gives:

```
Table created successfully
insert done
```

Check out docs @ https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html  Starting at **# Never do this -- insecure!**.